# Create a right triangle with loop in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I tried to solve the Visual Basic assignment in dart and I was able to using this :

[image]

I don't know if that's the best way to do it though. In Visual Studio I don't know what commands or methods that can help me do this and this is the result there.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim input As Integer
    
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = "Nested Loops"
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label.Click
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InputTextBox.TextChanged
        input = Val(InputTextBox.Text)
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub ComputeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComputeButton.Click
        For outer As Integer = 1 To input
            For inner As Integer = 1 To outer
                ListBox.Items.Add("#")
            Next
            ListBox.Items.Add("")
        Next
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

I get this error when trying to treat it like dart

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "#" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

I need help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose Winforms and the listbox? It would appear you wanted a [console app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-visual-basic-console?view=vs-2019).

Comment: So this is homework then?

Comment: `For outer As Integer = 1 To input ListBox1.Items.Add(New String("#"c, outer)) Next`. Maybe use a TextBox as output instead of a ListBox (which, btw, is named `ListBox1`). Or a RichTextBox, so you can color your lines. -- Or build a console app.

Comment: I chose Winforms because that's what we're using in school. This is not homework per se , just a try-out. I've spent a few days on this so far and the documentation from Microsoft is difficult to navigate and as well as to understand

Comment: Are *they* teaching you to use `Val()` (as in `input = Val(InputTextBox.Text)`) there? Can you change school? See [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
    For outer As Integer = 1 To input
        Dim s as String
        For inner As Integer = 1 To outer
            s &= "#"
        Next
        ListBox.Items.Add(s)
    Next
```

i.e. you want to have a string that grows by one # each time before you add it to the thing that will display it:

```
"#"
"##"
"###"
"####"
```

This uses simple string concatenation. In the future when you're programming for real (and e.g. wanting to run a process that creates millions of strings) you should consider using something designed for the job, such as  a StringBuilder. This will be ok for some small handful of operations though

Though I'm rather puzzled why you use a listbox and not just a textbox..

Comment: Thanks for the help, the '&' sign seems like what I had to use (forgot about it since I stopped using C and C++) abd  I had to use a listbox since it was required

Comment: VB will concatenate strings with `+` but its primary function is addition, so you get unexpected results with e.g. `"hello" + 0` - `&` is string only and will convert e.g. the 0 to "0" for a concat